# Linux command to find all instances of a file pattern?

Tags: linux, filesystems, grep, find

I'm looking for a way to scan a directory recursively and print out all instances of any file that ends ".qfx". Thus, for a given directory:

```
somedir/
    fizz.qfx
    buzz.qfx
    blah/
        foo.qfx
        widget.js
        meh/
            bar.qfx
            derp.gif
```

The output would be:

```
somedir/fizz.qfx
somedir/buzz.qfx
somedir/blah/foo.qfx
somedir/blah/meh/bar.qfx
```

I'm on Ubuntu so no preference in shell, python, perl, etc. Best attempt so far is:

```
find -name ".qfx" somedir
```

But getting the following error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: .
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec][path...] [expression]
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but asking this question is just ultimately lazy (despite it being verbose and nicely (time-consuming?) formatted.  The error tells you exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it tells you to put the directory before the `-name` expression. Also, you need a `*` to match for all files:

```
find somedir -name "*.qfx"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find /u02/fullbackup -name *.bck -print
find: paths must precede expression: arc_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2879_1.bck
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

solution:

```
find /u02/fullbackup -name '*.bck' -print

/u02/fullbackup/dbf_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2872_1.bck
/u02/fullbackup/arc_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2882_1.bck
/u02/fullbackup/arc_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2892_1.bck
/u02/fullbackup/arc_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2894_1.bck
/u02/fullbackup/arc_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2891_1.bck
/u02/fullbackup/arc_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2885_1.bck
/u02/fullbackup/dbf_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2871_1.bck
/u02/fullbackup/arc_381465332_OSOS_20160219_2888_1.bck
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case you're using `zsh` as shell, you can also use `ls **/*.qfx`, which is pretty useful.

Comment: also works in `bash` if the globstar option is enabled: `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: @mata true, however that is `bash version 4` or later.